# Error while checking request.method

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

When I try to do a if statement like this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'method'
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2000, in __call__
  return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
  response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
  return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1567, in handle_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
  raise value
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
  response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
  return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
  raise value
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
  return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "K:\HinaCh4n-PenSuite\main.py", line 75, in login_page
  raise e
File "K:\HinaCh4n-PenSuite\main.py", line 55, in login_page
  if request.method == "POST":
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'method'
```

Here are my imports:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, request, render_template, flash, url_for, redirect, session
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from dbconnect import connection
from pymysql import escape_string as thwart
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
from functools import wraps
import random
from base64 import b64encode
from wtforms import Form, BooleanField, TextField, PasswordField, validators
import gc
from urllib import request
```

And my function:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def login_page():
        error = " "
        try:
            c, conn = connection()
            if request.method == "POST":

                data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = (%s)", (thwart(request.form['username'])))
                print(data)
                if data < 1 :
                    return "0"
                else:
                    data = c.fetchone()[2]
                    if sha256_crypt.verify(request.form['password'], data):
                        session['logged_in']  = True
                        session['username'] = request.form['username']
                        return "1"
                    else:
                        return "0"

            gc.collect()

            return render_template("login.html")

        except Exception as e:
            raise e
            error = "Invalid credentials"
            return "error"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Check which method from `request` is being used? Like checking whether the method is `request.method()`?

Comment: Can you paste more of your code here? Stuff like the method this is used in, as well as any import statements would be useful.

Comment: just did it, added some more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're importing 2 separate `request`s (from flask and urllib), it's not working properly. Change your import for urllib's request to this, and update all references for urllib's request from `request` to `req`

```
from urllib import request as req
```